# Migrate iOS app to Android machine architecture

Tags: android, ios, types, migration

I'm migrating an iOS 5.0 application to Android 2.3.3.

This iOS app has an encryption algorithm that use some uint32_t variables.

I've found this on stdin.h:

```
#ifndef _UINT32_T
#define _UINT32_T
typedef unsigned int         uint32_t;
#endif /* _UINT32_T */
```

`uint32_t` is an `unsigned int` in Objective-C, so its equivalent in `Java` is `long`. Is this correct?

My question is:

**Does int, char, long, etc. Objective-C types have the same memory representation on Android?**

Answer (score 2):

No. Android (which is Java) does not have unsigned variable types.

So if you need to store a C unsigned 32bit integer then you'll need to use a long in Java but this will be 64 bits (so that you will be able to store the full precision of an uint32).

Any signed representation, instead, will have the same memory layout (but I'm not sure about endianness, you should check it by your own).

This is true unless you choose to use C/C++ in Android and skip Java (which can be done but you'll need to bridge API calls to Java with JNI in any case).

To solve similar issues I found a library, called **Javolution** which is able to provide a good implementation for C structs by maintaining same layout, take a look [here](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/io/Struct.html). But I was working with structs, not plain variables so this could not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Probably,I'm going to migrate this algorithm to C and use JNI. Thanks again!